# Perl : Removing spaces in lines

Tags: perl

I have the following file :

```
firstname=John
name=Smith
address=Som
 ewhere
```

As you can see, the address is on 2 lines (and the second line begins by a space).

I have to write the "good" output (with "address=Somewhere") into another file.

That's the first script (a little bit complicated) I wrote :

```
foreach $line (@fileIN) {
    if ($lastline eq "") {
        $lastline = $line;
    } else {
        if ($line =~/^\s/) {
            print $line;
            $line =~s/^\s//;
            $lastline =~s/\n//;
            $lastline = $lastline.$line;
        } else {
            print fileOUT $lastline;
            $lastline = $line;
        }
    }
}
```

$line =~/^\s/ => This regex is matching spaces in the $line, but not only at the begin.

I also tried to write a simple one but it doesn't work too :

```
perl -pe 's/$\n^\s//' myfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be doing too much work. I'd do it this way:

```
my $full_line;
foreach my $line (@fileIN) {
    if ($line =~ /^\s+(.+)\Z/s){                   # if it is continuation
            my $continue = $1;                     # capture and
            $full_line =~ s/[\r\n]*\Z/$continue/s; # insert it instead last linebreak
    } else {                                       # if not
            if(defined $full_line){ print $full_line } # print last assembled line if any
            $full_line = $line;                    # and start assembling new
    }
}
if(defined $full_line){ print $full_line }         # when done, print last assembled line if any
```

Comment: You could be using `chomp` like choroba, which would be the more "perl-like" way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For example like this?

```
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    print "\n" if /=/ and $. - 1; # do not insert empty line before the 1st line
    s/^\s+//;                     # remove leading whitespace
    print;
}
print "\n";                       # newline after the last line

__DATA__
firstname=John
name=Smith
address=Som
 ewhere
```

Comment: What if file will be in another format? There's no specific mention that each line should have single =, only that idented lines should be connected to previous.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov : Well, without a full specification, one can only guess.

Comment: A line can contain more than one = as you said :)

Answer (score 0):

check my solution only 1 regexp :)

```
my $heredoc = <<END;
firstname=John
name=Smith
address=Som
 ewhere
END

$heredoc =~ s/(?:\n\s(\w+))/$1/sg;
print "$heredoc";`
```

Comment: Is it possible to get an entire file in a variable and do the substitution on it ?
Like :
`open(FILE, "$myfile") || die "open: $!";
$FILE =~ s/(?:\n\s(\w+))/$1/sg;
print $FILE;`

Comment: @user1425653: `my $file = do {local $/; <$filehandle>};`